# The getter '_hasError' isn't defined for the class 'Future<T>'. - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'. Try correcting the name to the name of a getter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

In this code, I am passing the fetched data from the PHP API and it
is parsed and mapped by the JSON function successfully but I have
noticed that it does not return the value to the future builder which
is originally calling the fetchJson function and the following error
is displayed when i debug and the debugger reaches the variable alpha
in the future Builder below and then shows this error:

> <error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The
> getter '_chainSource' isn't defined for the class 'Future'.
>
> - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
>   '_chainSource'.
>   _chainSource
>
> <error: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The
> getter '_hasError' isn't defined for the class 'Future'.
>
> - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
>   '_hasError'.
>   _hasError ^^^^^^^^^>

```
Future<List<BodyModel>> fetchJson(http.Client client, String? id) async {
      final response = await client.get(
            Uri.parse(uri2),
          );
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            String jsonData = response.body;
        
            print(response.body);
            //print(jsonEncode(response.body));
        
            List<BodyModel> alpha = responseJSON(jsonData);
            //print(alpha.toSet());
            //bravo = alpha;
            return alpha;
          } else {
            throw Exception('We were not able to successfully download the json data.');
          }
        }
        
        List<BodyModel> responseJSON(String response) {
          final parse = jsonDecode(response).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
          print(parse.toString());
        
          final resp =
              parse.map<BodyModel>((json) => BodyModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
          print(resp);
          return resp;
        }
        onTap: () {
              id_get = model.id;
              final alpha = fetchJson(http.Client(), id_get);
              print(alpha);
              FutureBuilder<List<BodyModel>>(
                future: fetchJson(http.Client(), id_get),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ViewScreen(snapshot.data!);
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              );
            },
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
        class BodyModel {
          String body;
          String title;
        
          BodyModel({
            required this.body,
            required this.title,
          });
        
          factory BodyModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
            return BodyModel(
              body: jsonData['body'].toString(),
              title: jsonData['title'].toString(),
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please properly format the question? It is barely readable.

Comment: Add fetchJson method too

Comment: I have added the fetchjason function and apparently, the function is not returning any value while I have seen during debugging that on its return alpha it does hold the required value but it is not forwarding it in the future builder